# How to hide element based on its css property using JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

My task is to hide on button click elements with `align: center;` using jQuery

By clicking another button those elements must be shown

I tried doing this, but it changes property, not hides it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>jQuery Task 1</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <style>
        p {
            background: blue;
            color: beige
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<style>html, body {
    color: #777;
}</style>
<p style="display: none">Hello</p>
<p class="text" align="center">This is the paragraph</p>
<p class="text">This is the second paragraph</p>
<button id="but1">Click me to hide</button>
<button id="but2">Click me to show</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#but1").click(function () {
            $(('.text').css('text-align', 'center')).hide();
        });
        $("#but2").click(function () {
            $('.text').show();
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the *setter* of `css()`, so you're setting all the `.text` elements to central alignment, not filtering them.

To do what you require you can use an attribute selector to retrieve only the `.text` elements which have the `align="center"` attribute:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#but1").click(function() {
    $('.text[align="center"]').hide();
  });
  
  $("#but2").click(function() {
    $('.text[align="center"]').show();
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  color: #777;
}

p {
  background: blue;
  color: beige
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<p style="display: none">Hello</p>
<p class="text" align="center">This is the paragraph - hide this</p>
<p class="text">This is the second paragraph</p>
<button id="but1">Click me to hide</button>
<button id="but2">Click me to show</button>
```

***However*** the `align` attribute is very outdated and shouldn't be used. Instead you can use CSS `text-align` to set the text alignment via a class, then select the `.text` elements with that class on them. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#but1").click(function() {
    $('.text.center').hide();
  });
  
  $("#but2").click(function() {
    $('.text.center').show();
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  color: #777;
}

p {
  background: blue;
  color: beige
}

.center { text-align: center };
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<p style="display: none">Hello</p>
<p class="text center">This is the paragraph - hide this</p>
<p class="text">This is the second paragraph</p>
<button id="but1">Click me to hide</button>
<button id="but2">Click me to show</button>
```

If, for whatever reason, you can't set the class on the element and have to put the `style` rule inline, then you can use `filter()` instead:

```html
<p class="text" style="text-align: center">This is the paragraph - hide this</p>
```

```js
$('.text').filter((i, el) => $(el).css('text-align') === 'center').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

`.css('text-align', 'center')` doesn't test if the element has this alignment, it sets the alignment. Call `.css()` with a single argument to get the value of the style, and then test that with `==`.

But the `align` attribute doesn't necessarily translate to the `text-align` CSS property. For instance, in Chrome it creates the `--webkit-align` property. So you should use `.attr()` rather than `.css()` to test this.

The other answer that uses a single attribute selector is the more idiomatic way to do this, but I'm keeping this answer anyway to show how you do more general filtering when necessary.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#but1").click(function() {
    $('.text').filter(function() {
      return $(this).attr('align') == 'center';
    }).hide();
  });

  $("#but2").click(function() {
    $('.text').show();
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  color: #777;
}

p {
  background: blue;
  color: beige
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<p style="display: none">Hello</p>
<p class="text" align="center">This is the paragraph - hide this</p>
<p class="text">This is the second paragraph</p>
<button id="but1">Click me to hide</button>
<button id="but2">Click me to show</button>
```